# jQuery toggleClass won't toggle on a separate thumbnail click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**My goal**:

1. Have a set of thumbnails.
2. Click a thumbnail to toggleClass hiddenElement and show a large
   image inside a div that hidden.
3. Click anywhere in the DOM and it will hide or allow the user to
   switch to the next div (if that div's thumbnail #2 is clicked).

**My Problem**:
The image toggles just fine when clicked on or the DOM, except for when I click the second or third thumbnail etc.  It just keeps the original image up and load the next clicked image under the first leaving both images up.

So when clicking on the first thumbnail it loads the image, but when clicking on the second thumbnail, the first image fails to disappear and loads the second image as well under it.  It's supposed to toggle my CSS class hiddenElement.

**My jQuery**:

```
$("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").on("click", function() {
  $("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); 
});

$('document').click(function() {
  $('#port1_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
});

$("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").on("click", function() {
  $("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); 
});

$('document').click(function() {
  $('#port2_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
});
```

**My DOM**:

```
<div class="wrap">

    <!-- Hidden elements -->

        <div id="port1_large" class="hiddenElement">
            <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_content/project1.jpg">   
        </div>

        <div id="port2_large" class="hiddenElement">
            <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_content/project2.jpg">   
        </div>

    <!-- /Hidden elements -->

    <!-- Thumbnails -->

          <div id="portfolio">
              <ul class="portfolio-grid">
                    <li>
                        <a id="port1_thumb"  target="portfolio">
                            <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_thumbnails/thumbnail_1.png" alt="img01"/>
                            <h3>Project 1</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="port2_thumb"
                           target="portfolio">
                            <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_thumbnails/thumbnail_2.png" alt="img01"/>
                            <h3>Project 2</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

**CSS class**:

```
.hiddenElement {
    display: none;
}
```

**Notes**:

I have a lot of DRY going on, how can I bet simplify my code to prevent this toggleClass issue from happening?

*I think it's due to me repeating the action on the same class in my jQuery over and over, but I don't know how to refactor that.*

I did find a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMFb9/) of what's going on, however it's the exact problem I'm encountering.  Not being able to switch between thumbnails instead of one in particular.

If there is a tutorial or question posted about this exact topic of toggleClass for multiple elements not working please link it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think it's because when you click on #port2_thumb or #port2_large, #port1_thumb and #port1_large don't know about it. Try something like this : `$("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").on("click", function() {
  $("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); $("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); 
});`

Comment: I did try something similar to that, unfortunately it still loads both images at once.

Comment: You can also try to simplify your code with something like this : `$( "div[id^='port']" ).on("click", function() { $(this).toggleClass("hiddenElement");})`

Comment: Yeah I also tried that last night, it instead removed the thumbnails from the DOM.  I'm wondering if I should use a `data-target` instead, since I'm using a thumbnail to trigger a div in the DOM to show.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use addClass and removeClass until you get the results you want. After, you simplify with toggle(). Something like : `$("#port1_thumb").on("click", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("hiddenElement"); $('#port2_large').addClass("hiddenElement"); 
});` . Make some test and see if it's the behavior you expect. After, you can use toggle() to simplify the code.

Answer (score 1):

If i truly understand what you mean you need some thing like this:

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .hiddenElement {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">

        <div id="port1_large" class="hiddenElement large">
        <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_content/project1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="port2_large" class="hiddenElement large">
        <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_content/project2.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="portfolio">
        <ul class="portfolio-grid">
            <li>
                <a id="port1_thumb" class="thumb" target="portfolio">
                    <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_thumbnails/thumbnail_1.png" alt="img01" />
                    <h3>Project 1</h3>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="port2_thumb" class="thumb"
                    target="portfolio">
                    <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_thumbnails/thumbnail_2.png" alt="img01" />
                    <h3>Project 2</h3>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
       
        $("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").on("click", function ()
        {
            $("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement");
        });

        $('document').click(function ()
        {
            $('#port1_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
        });

        $("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").on("click", function ()
        {
            $("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement");
        });

        $("#port1_thumb").click(function ()
        {
            if (!$('#port2_large').hasClass("hiddenElement"))
                $('#port2_large').addClass("hiddenElement");
            $("#port2_thumb").removeClass("hiddenElement");
        });

        $("#port2_thumb").click(function ()
        {
            if (!$('#port1_large').hasClass("hiddenElement"))
                $('#port1_large').addClass("hiddenElement");
            $("#port1_thumb").removeClass("hiddenElement");
        });

        $('document').click(function ()
        {
            $('#port2_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes! That's almost what I'm trying to accomplish, I have more than a few thumbnails so I already saw what I messed up on in my DOM  (port2_thumb should be port_thumb2).  I'm onto something like a refactor of what you have: `$("div[id^='port_thumb']").click(function ()
        {
            if (!$('div[id^='port_large]').hasClass("hiddenElement"))
                $('div[id^='port_large]').addClass("hiddenElement");
            $('div[id^='port_thumb]').removeClass("hiddenElement");
        });`
I think I'll have to do a 'if' statement for has a class then remove class etc. Thanks!

Comment: if you have multiple thumbnail and multiple image add class to them. I add .thumb class to each link contains thumbnail and class .large to each large image. and the js: $('.thumb').click(function ()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            var thisId = $this.attr('id');
            $('.thumb').each(function () { $(this).removeClass("hiddenElement") });
            $('.large').each(function () { $(this).addClass("hiddenElement") });
            $this.addClass("hiddenElement");
            $('#' + thisId.replace("thumb", "large")).removeClass("hiddenElement");
        });